# AngularJS and PHP - make contents of POST array available in the application

Tags: php, angularjs

The thing works this way:

There is a mobile application, written in C# (probably, not sure, not relevant).
It sends a POST request with some data like user's nickname, e-mail address etc. to a site, let's say `mysite.com/index.php`. In this `index.php`, I can access the data (it is available in the `$_POST` array) for example this way:

```
<?php echo $_POST["nickname"];?>
```

My task is to rebuild the service at `mysite.com`, add some extra features to it etc. I have decided to use Angular as the front-end framework.

Now, what I am trying to do is to make the data sent in the request available in an AngularJS app - in fact I am able to do so, but I am not convinced that this is the way it should be done (the index.php of my Angular app looks like that):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.data = <?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>;  <<-- The "hack" is here
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <section ng-view></section>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the controller that makes this data available:

```
myAppControllers.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$window',
  function($scope, $rootScope, $window) {
    $rootScope.data = $window.data;
}]);
```

Question: is there any other (better, cleaner) way of doing so?

Comment: looks fine but maybe you want to do some `sanitation` or `validation` before print that `$_POST` ??

Comment: Thx for the answer! I will add some.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to take a look in to the [AngularPHP](https://github.com/urigoren/angularphp) sample project, it demonstrates a simple way to build a server-side API for angular in PHP